# news headlines not scrolling properly

Tags: html, css

I have made a news headlines div. The news flows from left to right smoothly. The only problem is my news text is block type. Every word is stacked on top of each other. How to solve this issue?

```css
#news_space {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:30px;
}

#news_headlines {
  padding-left:100%;
  animation-name:newsroll;
  animation-duration:10s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;

 }

@keyframes newsroll {
  from{transform:translate(0,0)}
  to{transform:translate(-100%,0)}
}
```

```html
<div id="news_space">
  <div id="news_headlines">
    <p>Big sales today!</p> <p>Big sales today!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `padding-left`, add `display: inline-block;` and some `width` to the `<p>` tags and change the animation `from{transform:translate(100%,0)}`.

Remember that both `<p>` must fit inside the parent element, else the second `<div>` will jump to next line.

```css
#news_space {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:30px;
}

#news_headlines {
  animation-name:newsroll;
  animation-duration:10s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

#news_headlines p {
  margin: 6px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes newsroll {
  from{transform:translate(100%,0)}
  to{transform:translate(-100%,0)}
}
```

```html
<div id="news_space">
  <div id="news_headlines">
    <p>Big sales today!</p>
    <p>Big sales today!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```